# How to disable Ubuntu loading dots during shutdown?

Tags: grub2, gnome, shutdown, gui, systemd

I've added my auto-backup script as systemd unit, that performs back up each shutdown. And now I wonder if I can disable ubuntu logo and loading dots **ONLY** during shutdown in order to see only TTY (console) in which systemd puts its output and errors.

Comment: did you try removing the package plymouth?

Comment: it will kick both boot & shutdown screens.

Comment: yes.. then you need to search for a plymouth theme which does not hide shutdown. Or you need to edit the plymouth theme script as per your needs..